# Sonarqube 6.7 community edition on Windows 10 fails to start

Tags: java, windows, sonarqube

I am trying to install and run SonarQube 6.7 community edition on Windows 10. The "quick start" option does not work: 
c:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-32\StartSonar.bat. 
The problem seems to be here:

```
Error: missing `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\server\jvm.dll'. Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components..
```

What am I missing? I just downloaded the latest JRE from java.com.

Comment: Did you unblock the zip before unzipping the SonarQube download?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install a `Server JRE` or `JDK` (Java SE 8). The JRE only is not enough to run SonarQube.

You can download them from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Java SE 8 version did not work for me. Had to install Java 11 version in order for the sonarQube.bat to run successfully